# Set ring volume programatically on Android phone using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The following code works well

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Vibrate;
```

So after running it the ring volume gets to 0, but I would want to set it to a custom value like for instance "57".

To do this I used the following code:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
am.SetStreamVolume(Stream.Ring, 57, 0);
```

After this code runs nothing changed to my ring volume, I expected that it will change to a "57" value.

I am using latest Xamarin libraries on a Android 7.0 version. I need to implement this only for Android.

Is this custom ring volume set a limitation ? 
What should this `am.SetStreamVolume(Stream.Ring, 57, 0);` actually do (if it is not changing the ring volume of the phone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [GetStreamMaxVolume](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Media.AudioManager.GetStreamMaxVolume/p/Android.Media.Stream/) firstly to get the maximum value for a particular stream, then set a proper number smaller than the maximum value.